# Docker Containers can not be stopped or removed - permission denied Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

**Issue**: Can not stop docker containers, whenever I try to stop containers I get the following Error message,

```
ERROR: for yattyadocker_web_1  cannot stop container: 1f04148910c5bac38983e6beb3f6da4c8be3f46ceeccdc8d7de0da9d2d76edd8: Cannot kill container 1f04148910c5bac38983e6beb3f6da4c8be3f46ceeccdc8d7de0da9d2d76edd8: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = permission denied
```

**OS Version/build:** Ubuntu 16.04 | Docker Version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4 | Docker Compose version 1.17.1, build 6d101fb

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Created a rails project with Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. docker-compose.yml is of version 3.
- Image is built successfully with either `docker build -t <project name> .` or `docker-compose up --build`
- Containers boots up and runs successfully.
- Try to stop docker compose with docker-compose down.

**What I tried:**:

- I have to run `sudo service docker restart` and then the containers can be removed.
- Uninstalled docker, removed docker directory and then re installed everything. Still facing same issue.

**Note**: This configuration was working correctly earlier, but somehow file permissions might have changed and I am seeing this error. I have to run `sudo service docker restart` and then the containers can be removed. But this is highly inconvenient and I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

**Reference Files:**

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local
  redis-data:
    driver: local  
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4.1
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file: local_envs.env
  web:
    image: yattya_docker:latest
    command: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - db
      - redis
      - memcached
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - memcached
    env_file: local_envs.env
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.4-alpine
    ports:
      # We'll bind our host's port 6379 to redis's port 6379, so we can use
      # Redis Desktop Manager (or other tools) with it:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      # We'll mount the 'redis-data' volume into the location redis stores it's data:
      - redis-data:/var/lib/redis
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
  memcached:
    image: memcached:1.5-alpine
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"
  clock:
    image: yattya_docker:latest
    command: bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: local_envs.env
  worker:
    image: yattya_docker:latest
    command: bundle exec rake jobs:work
    links: 
      - db
    depends_on: 
      - db
    env_file: local_envs.env
```

And Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.4.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV APP_HOME /app
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
RUN bundle install

ADD . $APP_HOME

RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/log
RUN cat /dev/null > "$APP_HOME/log/development.log"

RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/tmp/cache \
    && mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/tmp/pids \
    && mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/tmp/sockets

EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: Which user does start the containers?

Comment: I start containers on my ubuntu.. docker user created while installing docker must be used for managing containers. I am new to docker.

Comment: Did you add your user account to the docker group? `sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}` this will allow you to work with docker without sudo

Comment: @ShawnC is right (at least I suspect).
To validate you can run "sudo docker compose" or "sudo docker-compose down".

Comment: Yes.. I followed the guide and added docker to group, I can run docker commands without sudo. I am not having problem with `docker-compose up`, it's just causing trouble while removing or stopping containers.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Ubuntu 10.04, Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4, docker-compose version 1.8.0. Tried re-installing docker-ce with `apt-get prune` and `apt-get autoremove`. No luck. Restarting docker service with `sudo service docker restart` works.

Comment: @CharlieVieillard If you have properly set `sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}` and still facing issue then You might need to check whether apparmor is working fine or not. I had issues with apparmor, hence I re-installed docker and apparmor. And after **restarting laptop** the issue was resolved. I think issue is related to https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20554

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. Apparmor service in ubuntu was not working normally due to some unknown issue. The problem was similar to the issue reported in moby project https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20554.

The `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables` folder was empty, and https://github.com/mlaventure suggested to **purge/reinstall apparmor to get it to the initial state.**

So I reinstalled apparmor, and **after restarting** the problem was solved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Further details on docker hub forum: https://forums.docker.com/t/can-not-stop-docker-container-permission-denied-error/41142/5

Answer (score 259):

I installed Docker from the snap package and after a while I decided to move to apt repository installation.

I was facing the same problem and using `sudo aa-remove-unknown` worked for me.

So no reinstallation of Apparmor was needed.

Comment: This is the correct non-nuclear answer. Installing Docker as a `snap` adds a bunch of AppArmor profiles, that conflict with and `apt` installation. This happened to me by accident, as I was looking for a convenient method of installing everything Docker. Opted for an `apt` installation in the end, as it gave me more control and is more up-to-date.

Comment: Perfect answer !!

Comment: using ```sudo aa-remove-unknown``` causing my mysql workbench does not work and shows error: Failed to Query AppArmor Policy: No such file or directory. edit: all apps installed with snap don't work

Comment: I restarted my computer and the apps installed with snap has gone .. any idea ?

Comment: Still working through this, but for me, this did indeed appear to cause problems with at least some snaps.

Comment: I was able to get my snaps back working with: "sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/*"  Thanks to jdstrand, https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-confine-has-elevated-permissions-and-is-not-confined-but-should-be-refusing-to-continue-to-avoid-permission-escalation-attacks/5557/2

Comment: This seemed to work, however, after a reboot, the problem was back.

Comment: I got the same problem like @not2savvy . The problem is back after restart.  Have anyone solved this one completely ?

Comment: @ninoorta I was able to solve it for me. Please [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68132254/4850949).

Comment: Plus https://stackoverflow.com/a/54088663/4850949 AFAIR.

Comment: I'm a noob. For future people trying to use sudo aa-remove-unknown be careful how you use it because it ended removing some libraries necessary for other programs

Comment: Apps installed with the snap will not start after that

Answer (score 119):

For anyone that does not wish to completely purge AppArmor.

Check status: `sudo aa-status`

Shutdown and prevent it from restarting: `sudo systemctl disable apparmor.service --now`

Unload AppArmor profiles: `sudo service apparmor teardown`

Check status: `sudo aa-status`

You should now be able to stop/kill containers.

Comment: Attention! Some apps won't start after that

Comment: Be aware, any solution containing `apparmor` will break snap and all the packages installed via snap and even after that I still have problem with running and killing pods on kubernetes.

Comment: I followed the steps described above. Now some of my apps don't start anymore. How can I fix that?

Comment: @HerthaBSC I have the same issue. IntelliJ stopped working. I managed to temporary fix it.
Using `sudo apt purge snapd && sudo apt install snapd` solved the issue. But it I guess it purges the apps that weren't starting. IntelliJ, in my case. So, I had to install it again.
But once you reboot the system, you have to repeat the process. Did you manage to find a permanent solution?

Comment: If I remember it right, I disabled AppArmor as described in the solution above, then reinstalled Docker and reenabled AppArmor afterwards with `sudo systemctl enabled apparmor` and `sudo systemctl start apparmor`.

Answer (score 36):

A direct fix to the problem is executing bash in the container to be killed and directly calling `kill` there. An example:

```
host$ docker exec -it <container-name> sh
container$ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 {entrypoint.sh} /bin/sh /entrypoint.sh
   16 root      0:00 {entrypoint.sh} /bin/sh /entrypoint.sh
   24 root      0:00 sh
   31 root      0:00 ps
container$ kill 1
```

To check that the container was killed, run `docker ps`. This is a useful alternative to the solution reinstalling apparmor as this will also remove **snapd**.

Comment: this does not work, it just list `sh` and `ps` processes in my cases (from a docker-compose file)

Comment: I can confirm that this works. I also believe that this should be the accepted answer as this doesn't have any risks for your host system.

Comment: We had a different situation where ps showed that process 1 was running bash.  We had to kill -9 1 instead of just kill 1.  That worked to stop the container.

Comment: I have tried to run "kill  -9 1",  where "1" is the process id, but it stays. What else can I do ?

Answer (score 12):

In my case the issue was that I had conflicting docker installations: `docker` itself from the official [`docker-ce` package](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) , but `docker-compose` from the Ubuntu snap package.

Installing correctly `docker-compose` from the official github ([instructions here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)) did the trick. I also followed the [Linux post-install instructions](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) and it may have helped as well (to run docker as a non-root user)

I just left AppArmor alone here - I did not touch it.

Comment: Had the same issue. I saw that Docker was installed through snap: `snap list` and used `sudo snap remove docker` to remove it first

Answer (score 3):

it just simple resolves work for me

```
 sudo snap remove docker
```

Answer (score 2):

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
docker version: 20.10.17, build 100c701
docker-compose version: 1.29.2

I faced the same issue and tried following,

1. sudo systemctl disable apparmor.service --now
2. sudo service apparmor teardown
3. sudo aa-remove-unknown
4. reboot

These solutions didn't work for me.
This issue happens because of a security feature of linux kernal, apparmor.

We can disable it by running docker daemon as a non-root user(Rootless mode),
Execute following commands,

Solution:

1. curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh | FORCE_ROOTLESS_INSTALL=1
2. export PATH=/home/user-directory/bin:$PATH

docker-compose down or docker rm, will work

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with this for so long so first I realized I had to terminate the network that the container was one. So I followed all the steps for that. But I was still getting permission denied. Then just did

> sudo docker inspect portainer

And in the "State" -> "Pid", I then used the Pid with

> sudo kill

Answer (score 0):

for me

Problem: Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 0b21a3532fe2: permission denied
(base) ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-46:~/serverless$

Solution:

sudo service docker stop
sudo service docker start

**then stop all again**

docker stop $(docker ps -aq)

**if want to remove it then**

docker rm $(docker ps -aq)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35565919)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same "Permission denied" and was not able to stop the container using `docker kill`, or by exec'ing into the container and killing the running processes as proposed, or by using AppArmor.

However, this worked for me. If you don't mind removing the container, then force removing the offending container will also stop it:

```
sudo docker rm <container-id> -f
```