# Unable to restart the Docker machine

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-machine, prisma

I am trying to restart Docker using the command

```
sudo docker restart a7f8ce75f51f
```

but I get the following error

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container a7f8ce75f51f: Cannot kill container 
a7f8ce75f51f718c39828ef45e510e5380fee6d768a3496a251469f3afee650c: unknown error after kill: 
runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused
"permission denied"
: unknown
```

What could be the reason for this error?

I want to restart the Docker with this Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
prisma:
    network_mode: host
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4455:4466"
    environment:
    PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
        default:
            connector: mongo
            uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27018'
```

Comment: Have you try this > https://stackoverflow.com/a/56134376/1535270 ?

Comment: @abestrad Did not understand the answers

Comment: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56134376/1535270) of them suggested to remove the armor profiles using   `sudo aa-remove-unknown`. You may want first to run this with `-n  dry run; only prints the names of profiles that would be removed ` So, you understand the implications and possible outcome.                   [Armor Help Page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/aa-remove-unknown.8.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think, the message indicates that a process inside the container blocks the kill signal.
Since it is a db-container, maybe this is some sort of data protection.

You could try to manually stop it with:

```
docker stop a7f8ce75f51f
```

Comment: You might want to check out this link then:
https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower/issues/162#issuecomment-364838279
It looks like an error with AppArmor

Comment: Is there a way to check the compose file using which the docker was restarted / created?