# Problems starting docker instance

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apparmor

Not sure this is a docker problem specifically but this is how it goes: I tried `sudo docker stop 7f8c9285465c` which resulted in

`Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 7f8c9285465c: Cannot kill container...unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"`

Following [this stackoverflow suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223280/docker-containers-can-not-be-stopped-or-removed-permission-denied-error) I did `sudo aa-remove-unknown`. Now the `docker stop` succeeded but subsequent `docker-compose up` resulted in:

`snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks`.

Next I ran the command `sudo apt purge snapd snap-confine && sudo apt install -y snapd`. Now running `docker-compose up` results in

`bash: /snap/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory`.

The command `sudo docker container ls` results in:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

`sudo service docker status` returns `Active: active (running)`.

I tried reinstalling docker. running `sudo docker run hello-world` retunrs the same `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?` (although status is active)
.

Comment: For the first error, it seems `docker` is not part of `sudo` group, make sure it is. for the others, if you have installed `docker` via system package manager and also **snap** then you run into a kind of conflict (two versions). Remove both snap package and system and install just one

Answer (score 0):

Create file `/etc/systemd/network/bridge.network` with contents:

```
[Network]

IPFoward=kernel
```

If no permissions to save do so in root mode (`sudo su -`).

Then, run:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service # (disconnected network)
sudo apt remove docker-ce # If you hadn't done so before
sudo apt install docker-ce # Should start docker.service
sudo systemctl status docker.service  # Verify docker.service is running
```

This information has been taken from [this docker forum discussion](https://forums.docker.com/t/subprocess-installed-post-installation-script-returned-error-exit-status-1/37444/2).

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed docker with snap and installation of snapd is not complete  "snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks.

" this error indicates that "apparmor" service is not enabled.

```
 sudo systemctl enable --now apparmor
 sudo systemctl status apparmor
```

If apparmor is not installed install it:

```
  sudo apt-get install apparmor
```

this error "bash: /snap/bin/docker-compose" indicates that "/snap/bin" is not in your PATH. if you run this `snap --version` you might get an error saying "/snap/bin" is not in PATH.

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Add "/snap/bin"

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
```

Now you need to restart your system. Everything should be fixed.