# Docker containarized application refuses to die

Tags: docker, build

I am not very familiar to docker and its multiple applications. I use it to host [this NodeJS application](https://github.com/quivero/prego) by run of below command:

```
docker build -t quivero . && docker run --publish 8080:8080 quivero
```

It builds the application as we wish, but I have trouble to bring it down. I tried the usual `ctrl+C` or `ctrl+Z`. I tried as well `sudo docker kill $CONTAINER_ID`

`Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: $CONTAINER_ID: permission denied`

It seems to me `docker compose up` is rather preferred. What do you think?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223280/docker-containers-can-not-be-stopped-or-removed-permission-denied-error

Answer (score 1):

You can check running containers with command

```
docker ps
```

Then if you want to stop the container you need to write

```
docker stop [container name]
```

so for you

```
docker stop quivero
```

if you need to remove stopped container you can write

```
docker rm [container name]
```

Comment: This is the main issue on this post: I can run the commands you suggest, but those related to remove the container existence are resistant. It seems this container has great reasons to be alive. ;-P