# Docker composer cannot be stopped - permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker-compose cannot  be stopped.
Only rebooting the whole system helps.
Were started from non root user using the command:
`docker-compose up -d`

Command `groups $USER` is showing this:

sh adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev netdev lpadmin lxd sambashare **docker** .
So user is in group

Trying to stop from root doesn't help too.

```
sh@sh ~/D/c/ca2 (master)> docker-compose  down
[+] Running 3/3
 ✘ Container canna-redis       Error while Stopping                                         15.3s 
 ✘ Container canna             Error while Stopping                                         15.3s 
 ✘ Container canna-phpmyadmin  Error while Stopping                                         15.3s 
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: a6eefb47ad582c402792cd0df8bd530686499db6137e606cbd347263ca9435c5: permission denied
sh@sh ~/D/c/ca2 (master) [1]> sudo service docker restart
[sudo] password for sh: 
sh@sh ~/D/c/ca2 (master)> docker-compose  down
[+] Running 3/3
 ✘ Container canna             Error while Stopping                                         14.1s 
 ✘ Container canna-phpmyadmin  Error while Stopping                                         14.1s 
 ✘ Container canna-redis       Error while Stopping                                         14.1s 
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: a6eefb47ad582c402792cd0df8bd530686499db6137e606cbd347263ca9435c5: permission denied
sh@sh ~/D/c/ca2 (master) [1]> sudo docker-compose  down
[+] Running 3/3
 ✘ Container canna-redis       Error while Stopping                                         14.0s 
 ✘ Container canna             Error while Stopping                                         14.0s 
 ✘ Container canna-phpmyadmin  Error while Stopping                                         14.0s 
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: a2ff59a4b806a182be91b59cf44f8d235c5a65febe470cc465d98b0392509dfc: permission denied
```

I'm on Ubuntu 21.10.
sudo service docker restart   -  makes no effect

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: How were the containers started? Is docker running rootless? If not: Is the current user in the corresponding group (probably `docker`)? Can the containers be stopped with `sudo docker-compose down`?

Comment: [This question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223280/docker-containers-can-not-be-stopped-or-removed-permission-denied-error) might be of relevance. It looks like the problem could be caused by either apparmor or a mismatching combination of `docker-ce` from `apt` and `docker-compose` from `snap`.

Comment: @Turing85 That is. Easier to update distro to latest stable and not to repeat the mistake using the snap. Danke.  If zou place the short link- answer,I'll resolve it. Or just let it be hanging

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Containers can not be stopped or removed - permission denied Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223280/docker-containers-can-not-be-stopped-or-removed-permission-denied-error)

Comment: Yes, it looks pretty probably like. But I won't try the advice from there since risking the stability of the system is not an option