# docker unable to delete default network

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, devops, sre

When I start the docker-compose file all containers are working fine.

Docker File:

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgresql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: sonar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
      POSTGRES_USER: sonar
    hostname: postgresql
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
    - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql:rw
    - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    ports:
    - published: 8080
      target: 8080
    - published: 50000
      target: 50000
    privileged: true
    user: root
    volumes:
    - /home/jenkins_compose/jenkins_configuration:/var/jenkins_home:rw
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
  sonarqube:
    container_name: sonarqube
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
    hostname: sonarqube
    image: sonarqube:community
    ports:
    - published: 9000
      target: 9000
    volumes:
    - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data:rw
    - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions:rw
    - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs:rw
  sonatype:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    ports:
    - published: 8081
      target: 8081
    volumes:
    - sonatype-data:/data/db:rw
version: '3.8'
volumes:
  postgresql:
    driver: local
  postgresql_data:
    driver: local
  sonarqube_data:
    driver: local
  sonarqube_extensions:
    driver: local
  sonarqube_logs:
    driver: local
  sonatype-data:
    driver: local
```

After downing container.

i try with other container  faceing same issue.

Error:

```
Stopping sonarqube                ... error
Stopping postgresql               ... error
Stopping udamy-project_sonatype_1 ... error
Stopping jenkins                  ... done

ERROR: for udamy-project_sonatype_1  cannot stop container: b08e68f7e56a6a3ce7151ec7c867e8a4047350f9f95c290b6b59ca52d7213e1a: permission denied

ERROR: for sonarqube  cannot stop container: 89d8a8f75b36fdcb26e62d046dfb5d6ab9158f85d3cb5ef688968cade677b6fe: permission denied
Removing jenkins                  ... done
Removing network udamy-project_default
ERROR: error while removing network: network udamy-project_default id 94c01d2783cc2d34b4e917dd0f09ff5d0428b67ba1498277d9e9e132205dfb64 has active endpoints
```

I set all the permission from docker [Document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)  and reboot the system
OS : ubuntu 22.04

when I down the docker-compose file all containers are stopped and detached from the network.

I have tried to use multiple permutation and combination of these configs, but no luck.

Comment: This sounds like you're hitting [Docker Containers can not be stopped or removed - permission denied Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223280/docker-containers-can-not-be-stopped-or-removed-permission-denied-error).  That suggests a couple of resolutions around host configuration; does that help you?

Comment: @David Maze  I already try that resolution

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to run the compose file on my device. But I was able to run it by changing one line:

```
volumes:
- /home/jenkins_compose/jenkins_configuration:/var/jenkins_home:rw
```

to

```
volumes:
- ../jenkins_configuration:/var/jenkins_home:rw
```

and also able to remove the containers successfully by `docker compose down`

I guess the issue is with permissions on the `/home/jenkins_compose/jenkins_configuration` as it's on a different user (jenkins_compose)

Comment: The same issue does not work for me. @S. M. JAHANGIR