Docker custom program stop
Look at this c program:
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <signal.h>

   int stop = 0;

   void handle_signal(int sig)
   { 
      stop = 1;
   }

   void main() {
     signal(SIGINT, handle_signal);
     signal(SIGTERM, handle_signal);

     while (stop==0) {
       printf("Hello\n");
       sleep(1);
     }
   }

I am compiling this program statically:
gcc -static test.c -o test

And I am creating this Dockerfile:
   FROM scratch
   COPY test /test
   ENTRYPOINT ["/test"]

I am building the docker image:
   docker build -t myimage .

Finally, I run a container from this image:
  docker run --name mycontainer myimage

I have a problem: It is impossible to stop this container.
I have tried:

CTRL-C
docker stop mycontainer
docker kill mycontainer
exiting c loop when the program receives unix signals.

I am running Docker version 20.10.25 under kali Linux. gcc version: 13.3.0
I have this error when I try to run:
docker kill --signal=SIGINT mycontainer


Cannot kill container xxxx: Unknown error after kill: runc did not
terminate successfully: exit status 1: unable to signal init:
permission denied.

Please note there is only 1 file in my container. I have nothing else (bash, sh, ...)
My goal is to understand why the program is not exiting and why the container is not stopping.
Do you have any idea ? What's wrong in what I have done ?
Thanks

without explicit signal handling, program ignores termination requests thus preventing the container from stopping

Your program runs as PID 1 which has special rules attached to it. Normally PID 1 is the init process and killing it would bring Linux down. Take a look at tini which will run your program as a sub-process and make it easier to kill.

Thanks for your answer but popular images like nginx are also running as PID 1. How do they handle docker stop ?

I'm guessing that they implement signal handlers and terminate when they get a SIGTERM or SIGKILL

"exiting c loop when the program receives unix signals." You say you tried this, but you don't show it. Please edit your question to show your work.

See my edit: I have add signals handling

Be sure to run your container with docker run -it --name mycontainer myimage, otherwise the <cont>-c is likely going to docker and not your container.

I can't reproduce this on my system.  That being said, you might need stop to be volatile or to add mutex protect to ensure stop is actually read each iteration of the loop.

I couldn't reproduce the issue. Using your steps and programs, Ctrl-c does indeed stops executable. Please, can you tell us more : how do you know that the program is still running ? Do you see more "Hello" appearing after the signal ? Can you add a printf in handle_signal to observe if the callback happens ?

I couldn't reproduce the issue, too. (1) test.c , add #include <stdbool.h>, because my gcc give me error message: test.c:5:1: error: unknown type name ‘bool’ (2) my gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0 (3) first run. docker run --name mycontainer myimage , I can use Ctrl + C , stop the container (4) second run, docker start mycontainer, docker ps , make sure container is running,  then run command : docker stop mycontainer, docker ps, everything is ok.

Please not I am not running with "docker run -it". (see my question). I have also tried with "-d" option

@Bob5421 I understand that you do not run with the "-it" flags. Yet I can't reproduce "per say" which is way I'm requesting more information about your self diagnostic. What makes you think that it is still running ?

You said you tried to kill your container, but did you add --signal=SIGINT ?

yes I did. What I want to understand is how works nginx container for example. I can stop it properly...

Can't reproduce.  Please include your OS name and version, gcc version, and docker version.

I cannot reproduce. docker kill --signal=SIGINT mycontainer works correctly. I suspect there is something with your docker deamon setup, or this is a bug with previous versions of docker. Maybe something in your /etc/docker/deamon.json?

Can you inspect the binary/assembly output of your C code? stop misses volatile and it can be possibly optimized away. Also, you can try docker kill --signal=SIGKILL mycontainer as a workaround, but you probably know that already ;-)

The unable to signal init: permission denied makes me suspect it could be related to similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223280/docker-containers-can-not-be-stopped-or-removed-permission-denied-error. Is docker running within snapd?

I have no /etc/docker/daemon.json (only a key.json file).
I don't think it is an environment problem because I can run and stop an nginx container for example...

Maybe the program is not exiting, and the container is not stopping because processes running as PID 1 in Linux ignore default signals like SIGTERM and SIGINT unless explicitly handled.
If this is the problem, the solutions is to use a minimal init system like tini to properly forward signals.
Modify your Dockerfile to include tini:
FROM scratch
COPY --from=busybox /sbin/tini /tini
COPY test /test
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "/test"]

This ensures that signals are correctly forwarded to your program, and the container will stop as expected.

In a container built from scratch, there's no init system or shell to properly handle signals. Your program becomes PID 1 inside the container, which behaves differently regarding signal handling. I would use a minimal base image like alpine if using tini as a lightweight init system failed.
So instead of scratch, alpine that includes an init system:
FROM alpine:latest
COPY test /test
CMD ["/test"]

